# What's the correct way for persistent storage of an inner class in GAE/J JDO?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, inner-classes

From [GAE's documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/dataclasses.html), I can read this:

> The entity's kind is derived from the simple name of the class (inner classes use the $ path without the package name).

which does not tell me how to store it, and this:

> Here is an example of an embedded class. This example makes the embedded class an inner class of the data class that uses it; this is useful, but not required to make a class embeddable.

Why is it useful? What is the advantage of making the class "embedded"? How would I proceed if I do not need to "embed" it? **I'm having a hard time understanding this last statement.**

Let's say I have this class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class ChatHistory {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private ArrayList<Message> messages;
    // more fields and all the ChatHistory methods here

    private class Message implements Comparable<Message>{ // <-- This one
        public String timeStamp;
        public String text;
        // more fields and all the Message methods here
    }
}
```

How would you store it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious thing would be to make `Message` into a static class (the idea of trying to persist non-static classes makes my head hurt) and to annotate it with `@PersistenceCapable`. That will then cause it to be turned into its own table. You might be best advised to move it into its own file (and change it to 'package private') instead.

Comment: Moving into another file is my other option, but I'm sure there must be a way to store it as an inner class. I do not understand how making it static would help in this case. This is a one-to-many relationship in which each instance of Message is contained into an instance of the superclass. AFAIK, persistance of non-static classes is the way to store data in JDO. I would appreciate if you explained me why it makes your head hurt.

Comment: @Aleadam: Non-static inner classes work through the use of hidden fields (the reference to the context object is `final`, as would any references to final locals in containing contexts). Restoring any class requires writing to all its fields. Theoretically, it could all be done magically through bytecode enhancement anyway, but it's all messy. Save confusion, make the connections from `Message` to `ChatHistory` explicit or do away with them. And you *need* the `@PersistenceCapable` annotation (or you have to use the config file approach).

Comment: Moreover, a non-static inner class doesn't and can't have a no-arg constructor (even if you can't normally see that this is the case at the Java level). The only examples I've seen of inner classes used in persistence have been of static inner classes, which are no problem (at the low level, they're just classes with a slightly funny name).

Comment: @Donal I appreciate your explanation. I guess my problem is that I do not really know how the datastore works. I assumed there would be an easy solution for this, but that's probably no the case, and thus the "embedded" solution. For now, I'll just take the class out and store is as a regular class. Later, I'll have to do some reading about it.

Comment: As the JDO spec states, a *non-static* inner class cannot be made persistent, only a *static* inner class.

Comment: @Data: I was having trouble finding the spot in the spec where it said it, but I'm not at all surprised (on the grounds that I *know* “where many of the bodies are buried” in relation to how inner classes work in Java).

Answer (score 0):

Objectify — *a convenient datastore interface builded on top of GAE* — defines [@Embedded](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#@Embedded) for this kind of situation. If you don't have look for this kind of tool yet, it seems to be a good opportunity. If you do and prefere the low-level API, I cannot help you any further.

Comment: I will check on Objectify. In fact, I read only good things about it.